# SQL Server - Insert into table - All column values same except for 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-insert

Suppose I have the following insert statement for a table in my SQL Server 2008 DB:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
    ([Val1], [Val2], [Val3], [Val4])
VALUES
    ('val1', 'val2' 'val3', 'val4_a'),
    ('val1', 'val2' 'val3', 'val4_b'),
    ('val1', 'val2' 'val3', 'val4_c'),
    ('val1', 'val2' 'val3', 'val4_d');
```

In other words, all the values for `[Val1]` to `[Val3]` stay the same, but `[Val4]` keeps changing.

I was thinking to do something along the lines of:

```
Declare @Val1 varchar(10)
Declare @Val2 varchar(10)
Declare @Val3 varchar(10)   
Declare @Val4  ... some kind of list of varchar(10) ...

Set @Val1 = 'val1'
Set @Val2 = 'val2'
Set @Val3 = 'val3'
Set @Val4 = ('val4_a', 'val4_b', 'val4_c', 'val4_d')
```

and then do some kind of loop through `@Val4` with only one insert statement to write in that case. This allows for very easy changing / updating and would make my life substantially easier!!

I know this won't work - I only put it in as an example of what I'm hoping to accomplish - but what would be the best way to do such a thing?

Thanks and I hope the question makes sense!!

Comment: Where do values for @Val4 originate from? Is it a sequence, or something passed into procedure from client?

Comment: I would type them in myself... Imagine I have to update this DB for several car manufacturers and I have to choose which manufacturer to do it for... Sometimes it might be just 2, like `('Ford', 'BMW')`, other times it might be 10... It changes based upon the customer request.

Comment: Then Gordon's answer should work just fine.

Comment: @dean, See my response to him, please... That would mean commenting out some update statements / adding in new ones as the number of values in `@Val4` changed...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write arbitrary queries for your `INSERT`, if you use `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
    ([Val1], [Val2], [Val3], [Val4])
SELECT 'val1','val2','val3',v4.v
FROM (SELECT 'val4_a' union all
      SELECT 'val4_b' union all
      SELECT 'val4_c' union all
      SELECT 'val4_d') v4(v)
```

Of course, if you already have a [table variable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175010.aspx), say `@v4` containing one row for each desired value, it's even easier:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable 
    ([Val1], [Val2], [Val3], [Val4])
SELECT 'val1','val2','val3',v4.v
FROM @v4 v4
```

And of course, then, it can insert 1 row, 4 rows, 100000 rows, however many you've put in `@v4`.

---

So, a complete script could be:

```
DECLARE @v4 table (v varchar(10) not null)
INSERT INTO @v4(v) VALUES ('val4_a'),('val4_b'),('val4_c'),('val4_d')

INSERT INTO MyTable 
    ([Val1], [Val2], [Val3], [Val4])
SELECT 'val1','val2','val3',v4.v
FROM @v4 v4
```

Comment: Thanks, Damien, but the challenge is that this would still require making quite a few more changes than just creating a list and somehow looping through it... I don't know if it's possible, though... But can you see how this would be difficult if, one time `@val4` contained 3 values and the next it contained 10?

Comment: I just did!! - Thanks for the update Damien, could you help me with what would be the best syntax for creating `@v4` so that it would be flexible??

Answer (score 1):

You can use variables in the `values` statement.  So:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable([Val1], [Val2], [Val3], [Val4])
VALUES
    (@val1, @val2, @val3, 'val4_a'),
    (@val1, @val2, @val3, 'val4_b'),
    (@val1, @val2, @val3, 'val4_c'),
    (@val1, @val2, @val3, 'val4_d');
```

Does that accomplish your goals?

Comment: Thanks, Gordon, I know I can use them, but I'm looking to, for example, make `@Val4` a list and then not have to change the update statement at all.... Does that make sense? Kind of loop through all values in `@Val4`...